# More than +root verb?

Tags: idioms

> Mona Lisa was commissioned to celebrate the birth at a baby boy. Interestingly,  there is more than **meets** the eye. They have suggested that by magnifying lady's eyes under a microscope,  tiny letters and numbers can be seen.

How come it is possible to use root form after preposition or conjunction "more than"?

Comment: To celebrate the birth **of** a baby boy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[***More than meets the eye***](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.collinsdictionary.com/amp/english/more-than-meets-the-eye) 
Is a phrase meaning **more than there appears to be at first**

Comment: Really appreciate!