# Had commissioned into commissioned?

Tags: past-perfect, past-simple

> Mona Lisa was commissioned to celebrate the birth at a baby boy. The lady in the painting was Lisa del Giocondi,who was a member of the Gheradini family in Florence. It is assumed that the family **had commissioned** the painting to celebrate the birth of their second son,Andrea.

If i replace **had commissioned** with **commissioned,**  then the meaning would be changed?

Comment: As I [previously](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/204577/more-than-root-verb#comment395865_204577) commented when you asked a different question about this passage, it should be *the birth **of** a baby boy*.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't change the meaning. The use of *had* indicates that the commissioning is further in the past than the time of the context, but that is semantically obvious anyway, so it is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

No, the meaning would not change fundamentally.
The use of `had` in similar contexts may help to make things clearer, but I can't see how a native speaker would misunderstand this piece if it was dropped.